# Webi Query panel does not show full list of objects

Tags: business-objects, webi

I am facing an issue whereby Webi doesn't display all the available objects and I can't scroll down in the Result Query Panel as per attached screenshot. Please help on this, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using Freehand SQL, which is a fairly new feature and not fully baked yet.

I tried it out (SP06 Patch 5), and had the same result.  However, when I dragged the right-hand border out a bit, the vertical scrollbar magically appeared and I was then able to scroll down.  Not sure if that'll work for you.